# Go Pregnant or Go Home

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, steganography

A love story:

First, we met on the dance floor at this place playing loud music.
Soon after we were madly in love!
Before I knew it, we were engaged to be married.
Now, here I am in the backyard turning over soil for her garden instead of playing cards with my friends or enjoying the multitudes of brain-bending puzzles on my favorite website. Oh well, she's worth it.

---

---

Soon enough, of course, she peed on a plastic stick and it came back **＋**. We were so excited!

One day, after she had had a visit to her "special" doctor, I came home from work to find her sitting at my poker table with a big smile on her face.

I said, "Do you have any news?"

She nodded convulsively.

"When are we due, honey?"

That's when things got hairy.

"Well," she said, "seeing as how you spend every waking moment that you can on that *damn* Puzzling website or playing cards with your buddies instead of spending time with me, I've decided to torture you."

My smile lost some of its intensity. Through gritted yet still-smiling teeth I managed to ask, "Whatever do you mean, my little buttercup?"

"Don't give me any of that crap, Buster! I'm not telling you the due date until you figure out my *own* little puzzle. Once you solve the puzzle I have made here, then I will tell you our due date. To reemphasize, **this puzzle has nothing to do with the due date, do you understand?**"

I gulped and nodded.

Then she handed me a piece of paper which had this information on it:

- March 12, 2019
- June 18, 2019
- June 25, 2019
- September 10, 2019
- December 10, 2019

> What is the answer to her puzzle?

Comment: Sounds like homework help

Comment: @MichaelFulton What kind of homework assignment could this possibly come from?! (Or is this r/woooosh?)

Comment: Chowzen's a regular and active contributer here, I'd be incredibly surprised if this turned out to be homework. Unless I too am missing an inside joke.

Comment: @Phylyp I believe his wife is the "teacher"

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The introductory paragraph is a clue to

> A pack of cards. The lines point towards CLUB, HEART, DIAMOND, SPADE. There are also a few other pointers (e.g. poker table)

As [Arnaud](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81052/20466) has pointed out

> The dates represent the 11th, 25th, 26th, 37th and 50th Tuesdays in 2019. Converting these numbers into cards (using the order of suits defined above) we get Jack of Clubs, Queen of Hearts, King of Hearts, Jack of Diamonds, Jack of Spades. As a poker hand this is Three of a Kind, so perhaps our couple are expecting triplets. The hand could also be taken as a representation of the family: King = dad, Queen = mum, 3 Jacks = 3 sons.

Comment: If this isn't the answer I'm going to eat my hat

Comment: Go big or go home, even in pregnancy. I'm very glad that you continued your thoughts after rot13(guerr bs n xvaq), your second, familiar supposition was my intention. I'm ordering your green checkmark from Amazon.com, so it may take a little while before it gets here. :)

Answer (score 19):

The answer could be

> ESTER

Which I believe would mean that

> Your wife has chosen a name for the baby.

For the reason that

> The first of these Tuesdays is the `11`th tuesday of the year; the second is the `25`th, and so on resulting in the sequence: $$11\, 25\, 26\, 37\, 50$$
> If you set $$1=A, 2=B,\ldots, 26=Z,\qquad 27=A, 28=B,\ldots$$ this gives the word $$KYZKX$$
> which after a $-6$ Caesar shift gives $ESTER$.

Comment: Wow! That would be a good puzzle in itself. +1. Unfortunately, it doesn't [explain the beginning of the story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81045/go-pregnant-or-go-home/81053#comment236567_81049).

Comment: Jung vs gur onol jrer qhr ba Rnfgre?

Comment: @user45266 Thought about that too :) but the puzzle is not supposed to have anything to do with the due date.

Answer (score 15):

> It's a **TWIN**

as

> All these days fall on Tuesdays. 
>  Tuesday = 2's day. 
> So, she might me pointing that due date will be 2's day as she is having a twin.

Comment: A valiant attempt, but there's more to it than that. The opening love story (above the horizontal rules) is not mere fluff; it's part of the puzzle.

Comment: Everything before the horizontal rules is single spaced, but everything after is double spaced

Answer (score 4):

Looking back at the events that have been mentioned in the story-line:

> There are 5 major events mentioned, and 5 dates given to him by his wife. So, I would think those are the dates to those 5 events.

So,

> First, we met on the dance floor at this place playing loud music. => **March 12, 2019**

Then,

> Soon after we were madly in love! => **June 18, 2019**

Then,

> Before I knew it, we were engaged to be married. => **June 25, 2019**

Then,

> Now, here I am in the backyard turning over soil for her garden instead of playing cards with my friends or enjoying the multitudes of brain-bending puzzles on my favorite website. => **September 10, 2019**

Then,

> The 5th date, that is the only one remaining, **December 10, 2019** is the due date.

Comment: Hmm...I like the thinking, but If the due date is just _under_ 9 months after they first met and about 8 months after they fell in love....what I'm trying to say is, the baby usually takes about 9 months to be born. How did they not know that she had been pregnant the whole time? Did they....um....do something the night they first met? Things seem to be moving along quite quickly!

Comment: I was prompted to think in the same way, but even with that logic, I was having the same answer.

Comment: Maybe we should ask her mailman with upraised eyebrows? :) Great guess, but not quite on track.

Comment: I just realized—This answer is invalid due to the (true) fact pointed out by the wife: "this puzzle has nothing to do with the due date, do you understand?"